# How to end user session via Firebase Function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I made a Firebase Function which will detect invalid requests and block user accounts:

```
if (!context.auth)
    return null;

if (!(typeof data.text === 'string') || data.text.length !== 0)
{
    return admin.auth().updateUser(context.auth.uid, { disabled: true });
}
```

but the user can still call the function while authenticated. **How to end user session inside the cloud function and force the user to authenticate again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revoke a user's refresh token using the Firebase Admin SDK. This is available for various languages, but in Node.js it'd look like:

> ```
> // Revoke all refresh tokens for a specified user for whatever reason.
> // Retrieve the timestamp of the revocation, in seconds since the epoch.
> admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
>     .then(() => {
>       return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
>     })
>     .then((userRecord) => {
>       return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
>     })
>     .then((timestamp) => {
>       console.log("Tokens revoked at: ", timestamp);
>   });
> ```

For more on this, see [revoking refresh tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) in the documentation.